# how can i exclude the index from my output when using pandas df.loc?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

From a pandas df i'm trying to output the respective description name, based on the style code (UBR-5912).  It outputs the description but it always outputs the index number as well (8338).  How can i exclude the index in the output?

I'm using this output later on and it only takes on one output.  Thanks.

```
df.loc[df['STYLE_NO'] == 'UBR-5912', 'DESCRIPTION']
```

output:

```
8338    PADDED U/WIRED BRA
Name: DESCRIPTION, dtype: object
```

desired output

```
PADDED U/WIRED BRA
Name: DESCRIPTION, dtype: object
```

Comment: If you just want values, add `.values`

Comment: I agree with @BeRT2me . I can't imagine a scenario where you need column name and datatype.

Comment: it works thanks, but it outputs: " array(['PADDED U/WIRED BRA'], dtype=object)"
can i output only the description without the array [] and dtype info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option:
Edit: As per my understanding you are trying to output column `DESCRIPTION` value. My code is doing just that. I provided my full code with example `df`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STYLE_NO':['UBR-5912'],
               'DESCRIPTION': ['ABCD']})

print(df.loc[df['STYLE_NO'] == 'UBR-5912', 'DESCRIPTION'][0])

ABCD
```

Comment: This won't print the entire column just the first value. try this `data = {'customer_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1}, 'product_id': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'C', 3: 'B'}, 'sum': {0: 20, 1: 10, 2: 30, 3: 40}}; df.loc[df['customer_id'] >=1, 'product_id'][0];`

Comment: Yeah..I know. But his question is not with `inequality`. I shared the answer as it solve the question asked & it's simple. This is very similar to `.value` mentioned in question comment. But my answer return value rather than list.

Comment: sorry didn't get you,  I am saying that instead of gettting the series your approach just gives a scalar value

Comment: sorry, actually I'm trying to just output one single value (without the array[] with it).  
but when i try "df.loc[df['STYLE_NO'] == 'UBR-5912', 'DESCRIPTION'][0]"
i get KeyError: 0

Comment: This is very standard code. So, not sure why it's throwing error. I shared this code because it will give you single value, unlike `.value`, which return a `list`. And I highlighted this in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

In your case this would be

```
df.loc[df['STYLE_NO'] == 'UBR-5912', 'DESCRIPTION'].to_string(index=False)
```

You can also use [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='plain', showindex=False))
```

Checkout [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/), it can print your table in multiple pretty formats